# How can i import pdf files dynamically into react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, file-loader

i am working on a react app, created using "create-react-app". i have many pdf files stored in my public folder, inside an assets folder: public/assets/file.pdf

my app has to be running locally (without web server) and i need to load these files in order to display them. i cannot store the files elsewhere and get them via axios. it has to be from the public path

If someone has the info on how to do this, please enlighten me. thank you

I have tryed to do it this way : import("assets/filename")
i tried to put different urls, i took a look at the webpack config even tho i am no expert.
But it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf), it may help